# How to refresh my Textview from another activity

Tags: java, android

In my app, I am deleting data from my databasehelper class, and I want the Textview in the mainActivity to display the new changed data.So far this is my code.

```
public void DeleteData(){

    bDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Integer deletedRows = myDb.deleteData(etID.getText().toString());

        if(deletedRows > 0) {
            reload.Redraw();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Shit should work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }})
```

This is in my second activity, where I call the refresh function

```
public void Redraw() {
    displayMsg.postInvalidate();
}
```

Just in case, my text

```
  public void nexttime() {
    Cursor res = myDb.GetFirstTime();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
      displayMsg.setText("No Appointment was found");
        return;
    }
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (res.moveToNext()) {

      StringBuffer nextA = buffer.append("Date :" + res.getString(4) + "\n");
      displayMsg.setText(nextA);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your main activity update its own `TextView` in its `onResume()`.

Whenever one activity is running, **other activities do not exist.**  More precisely, they *may* exist, but you can never depend on it.  Never attempt to directly access one activity instance from another.